# Page post targeting and gating together

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page, targeting

What is the outcome if you use the new newsfeed targeting mechanism for a Page Post along with the old targeting, now called gating, mechanism. I can see three scenarios of how the results of these two mechanisms can overlap:

- If the targeted group is a subset of the gated group, everyone within either group will be able to see the post on the page, but only those in the targeted group will see it in their newsfeed.
- If the targeted group is a completely separate set with no overlap, then the people in the gated group will see the post on the page, but no one will see it in the newsfeed.
- If the the target group only overlaps partailly with the gated group, then everyone in the gated group will see the post on the page, and only those in the overlap will see the post in their newsfeed.

Is this correct?

Comment: Can you both gate and target through the api? There isn't much reference to post gating in the publishing docs https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/

Comment: In the documentation, old targeting (Gating) uses the "targeting" parameter and new Targeting uses the "feed_targeting" parameter. The api does not currently prevent you from doing this. At one point, you couldn't do this through the Facebook UI, but now you can.